# How do I copy one PHP script into another?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP, so I have a basic question.

I have this php script called hello.php. Basically I want to create a new php script exactly the same as `hello.php`, but with a unique name.

This is what I am thinking of doing, please tell me if it is in in the right direction.

```
$temp = tempnam(directory, prefix).'.php';
```

This creates a unique name, and appends .php to it so it will be a php file. 
How do I write the content of hello.php into `$temp`? I'm familiar with fwrite to write strings into the file, but what about writing all the codes from a different file, such as `hello.php`?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for [`copy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)?

Comment: ... why? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify: Your question is "How do I copy a file (hello.php) into a new file named $somevar . `.php'?"

Comment: @ceejayoz, +1. I don't understand either. Probably, it's self-issued task to learn php :)

Comment: @Nemoden I'm just afraid it's someone who's making a blog engine or something and trying to do what `mod_rewrite` is supposed to be doing.

Comment: How about <?php include('old_file.php'); ?> in new file? :)

Comment: Yes, that's right ken. I think copy would work. I think I was thinking of some really complicated method for some reason. I want the file to have a unique name (that's why I am using tempnam). I looked at the info for temp name, and it said that it only generate a name, not the file itself. So would the the variable $temp from tempnam work as the destination argument?

Comment: tim, sure it will if you have enough rights (user who runs php) to write to the `directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$file = 'example.txt';
$newfile = 'new.txt';

copy($file, $newfile);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`copy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)(`source`, `dest`)